# Fill up white space when Plotting Multiple Raster Images

Tags: r, image, plot, raster

How do I minimize the amount of white space in the following image whilst maintaining the image aspect ratio?

[image]

I specified `mar=c(0,0,1,0)` margins but the images are still spaced out. There's extra spacing on the left, center, bottom, and right. I want the images to be assorted in a grid with very little spacing between them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(EBImage)
library(png)

pngs<-lapply(seq(1:4), function(x) {
   readPNG(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))
})

par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(0, 0, 1, 0))
invisible(sapply(seq_along(pngs), function(i) {
  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), asp=1)
  rasterImage(pngs[[i]], 0, 0, 1, 1)
  title(paste0(letters[i], '. Image ', i), font.main=2)
}))
```

Comment: Did you try to increase the height of the plot window?

Comment: I tried adjusting the `xlim` and `ylim` in `plot.window()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `asp=1` the images keep the original aspect ration of `512:768` in your example. Conversely, your default plotting device seems to have an aspect ration close to `1:1`. This does not match well and causes the blank spaces.

**Two solutions:**

1. Set `asp=NA` to let the images use the entire space of the device by distorting them.
2. Adjust the size of the plotting device by setting the `width` and `height` arguments of `dev.new()`. For example:

   ```
   library(EBImage)
   library(png)
   png <- readPNG(system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"))
   dev.new(width=4.5, height=8)
   par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(0, 0, 1, 0))
   for(i in seq_len(4)){
       plot.new()
       plot.window(xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), asp=1)
       rasterImage(png, 0, 0, 1, 1)
       title(paste0("Image ", i))
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If other features of the `png` package aren't essential, here's another solution that takes advantage of `EBImage`. EBImage maintains the aspect ratio unless the image is intentionally transformed.

This solution requires more work to place the plot labels with `text()` but the increased cost may be offset by having more flexibility.

```
# Starting from EBImage
  library(EBImage)
  fn <- system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage")

# Single EBImage object with same four pictures
  pngs <- readImage(rep(fn, 4))

# Select spacing and margin for EBImage display/plot function
  spacing <- 50 # pixels between images
  margin <- 50 # pixels around edge
  nx <- 2 # number of rows for composite
  ny <- 2 # number of columns for composite
  dm <- dim(pngs)
  nframes <- dm[length(dm)]
  yadj <- -0.2 # offset for labels in y direction

# Indices, coordinates, and labels for text
  index <- seq_len(nframes)
  ix <- (index - 1)%%nx
  iy <- (index - 1)%/%nx
  xx <- ix*(dm[1] + spacing) + dm[1]/2
  yy <- iy*(dm[2] + spacing)
  labs <- sprintf("%s. Image %d", letters[index], index)

# Plot composite and add "titles" with text() function
  plot(pngs, all = TRUE, nx = nx, margin = margin, spacing = spacing)
  text(xx, yy, labs, adj = c(0.5, yadj))

# To eliminate ANY space in the composite make the following
# changes and re-run the code from "# Indices, coordinates..."
  spacing <- 0
  margin <- 0
  yadj <- 1.2
  dev.new(width = nx*dm[1]/200, height = ny*dm[2]/200) # 200 dpi image
```